# AWS lambda body object can't be mapped(values can't be accessed)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS lambda with API gateway. I can access the body inside event object using dot notation. Here is the schema of body

```
{
  "items": {
    "1681393109842MIN:01GXX9JHKHP5ZDW92NRRNPBHA4": {
      "name": "Chicken Tandoori",
      "price": 300,
      "qty": 2
    },
    "1681399155580MIN:01GXX9JHKHP5ZDW92NRRNPBHA4": {
      "name": "Mutton Tandoori",
      "price": 400,
      "qty": 2
    }
  },
  "message": "This is a dummy message"
}
```

`event.body` provides access to the body object but after that I cannot access the values using dot operator or anything.

What have I tried:

- Using square brackets with key to access data.
- Deepcopying the object

Comment: Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Lambda Proxy Integration, you receive a JSON string in `event.body`, therefore you need to parse it like so:

```
const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
console.log(data.message); // now you can access it using dot notation.
```

This can be seen in the [official AWS Lambda Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html):

```
if (event.body) {
    let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
    ...
    ...
}
```